# webservices in qt

Tags: c++, web-services, qt

I was reading of this and I find a lot of suggetions, use qtsoap, gsoap or QNetworkAccessManager but I can find a good example to do this. Where can I found one example where is explained how to call a web service inside QT, I need this done for today and I don't have much idea on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pessimism: QT itself doesnt offer you much, source: [here](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2010-September/027417.html) and [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/5091)

The hope: 3rd party solutions can help you, like [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)

Comment: great, I already generate all files with gsoap I need now to find how to interact in qt with that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As 3rd party libraries, i would suggest:

1. [GSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) IMHO must suggested library for c++ and webservice. But no native Qt support
2. [KD SOAP](http://www.kdab.com/kd-soap) as Qt native support.